# How can I format a column of numbers in an emacs org mode table?

Tags: bash, sorting, emacs, org-mode

I have a table in this form, in emacs `org-mode`. Please, is there a way to format the numbers in columns 3 and 4 to line the decimal points up vertically?

Note, an aside: I sorted the resulting file using bash `sort` command, and found that the extra `|` at the start of each line is counted as column 1, so, for instance the column headed `OUTPUT` is number 4 in this context.

```
| CALL  | CHAN   |   OUTPUT |    INPUT | QTHR   | LOCATION       | NGR        | REGION   | CTCSS | KEEPER | Internet |
| GB3AH | RB11   |  433.275 |  434.875 | JO02KP | East Dereham   | TF94300990 | EAST ENG |  94.8 | G8PON  |          |
| GB3AS | RV48   |    145.6 |      145 | IO84LS | Wigton,Cumbria | NY33724123 | N.ENG    |    77 | G4KFN  |          |
| GB3AG | RV58   |  145.725 |  145.125 | IO86ON | Forfar         | NO48904170 | SCOT     |  94.8 | GM1CMF | Echolink |
| GB3AY | RV52   |   145.65 |   145.05 | IO75OR | Dalry          | NS26605190 | SCOT     | 103.5 | GM3YKE |          |
| GB3BA | RB01   |  433.025 |  434.625 | IO87SC | Banchory       | NJ72150255 | SCOT     |    67 | GM1XEA |          |
| GB3BD | RB06   |   433.15 |   434.75 | IO92RA | Ampthill       | TL01303860 | SE ENG   |    77 | G8MGP  |          |
| GB3AA | 23cm   |     1297 |     1291 | IO81RO | Alveston,Avon  | ST62608820 | SW ENG   | 118.8 | G4CJZ  |          |
| GB3AI | RV55   | 145.6875 | 145.0875 | IO91QQ | Amersham       | SU97089767 | SW ENG   |    77 | G0RDI  | Echolink |
| GB3AL | RV59   | 145.7375 | 145.1375 | IO91QP | Amersham       | SU95709550 | SW ENG   |    77 | G0RDI  |          |
| GB3AM | R50-13 |    50.84 |    51.34 | IO91QP | Amersham       | SU95709550 | SW ENG   |    77 | G0RDI  |          |
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. This is an optional one, to make things a bit more visual.
   <kbd>C-c }</kbd> turns on the overlays for row and column numbers.
   Same combination turns the off. Note that these are not the changes
   in your buffer, they're just tooltips.
   You might want to do <kbd>C-c -</kbd> on the first line, to see
   the column numbers.
2. Move cursor to `OUTPUT` column and insert a new column with <kbd>C-S-right</kbd>.
3. Your cursor should now be in the new column.
   Type in `$4=$3;%0.3f`, i.e. copy the third column to the fourth,
   and format it as a floating point with 3 precision.
   Press return, and just one cell will fill in.
   Press <kbd>C-u C-c *</kbd> to recalculate all cells.
   This can also be done with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, with cursor
   on `#+TBLFM:` line.
4. You can remove the old column with <kbd>C-M-left</kbd> if you want,
   and delete the table formula below.

### UPDATE:

Thanks to input from @phils, here's the alternative way:

1. Move your cursor to any number in column 3, e.g. `433.275`.
2. Press <kbd>C-c =</kbd>, cursor moves to minibuffer.
3. Enter `$0;%0.3f` and press return.
   Here `$0` refers to the current column, `$3` would also work if it were column 3.
4. Either press <kbd>C-u C-c *</kbd> anywhere in the document,
   or move the cursor to `#+TBLFM:` line and press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.
5. Repeat the same process for column 4.

Comment: Thank you abo-abo for that. Please forgive my ignorance, but I can't see where those commands are entered, so could you please give a few more detailed instructions?

Comment: It's possible that some of the behaviour has changed between org versions 7 and 8? In vanilla Emacs 24.3, use `M-S-<right>` to insert a new column (left of current column), and type `C-c =` in the column to begin entering the formula in step 3.

Comment: It also looks like you can use `$0;%0.3f` (i.e. specifying `$0` as the source) as a formula to reformat the values in the current column (without needing to create a new column). So you could set that same formula in all the columns which need this formatting, and then recalculate the table display with `C-u C-c *` as shown.

Comment: Making @phils' comment more explicit, you can do, say, `$3=(some formula);%0.3f` to format the output of another formula.

Comment: To avoid loss of precision for derived values such as column sums, the derived values should be based on the original values, not on the reformatted values.  To make the original values as little visible as possible, set the column width to 2 by placing `<2>` somewhere in the column and then re-aligning.  See [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html).